# Sessions are lost when reloading partial pages

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-state, sha512

I have an issue where some of my pages take an extended period to load due to communications with various external APIs. I noticed that when I change to a different page or reload the current page before it has finished loading, it seems to drop my session and logs me out.

For example, if loading page about.php and then I click a link to load profile.php before about.php has loaded fully, it logs me out and drops me back at the login screen.

I don't know what to search for this but have not been able to find any information on similar problems. Can anyone shed light on what would be causing this?

Top of each page:

```
sec_session_start();

if(login_check($dp_conn) == false)
{
    header("location:../login.php?error=1");
}
```

sec_session_start() function:

```
function sec_session_start()
{
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.

    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.  
}
```

login_check() function:

```
function login_check($db)
{
    // Check if all session variables are set
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string']))
    {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user.

        $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = " . $user_id . " LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            // If the user exists
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $password = $row[0];
            $login_check = hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser);

            if($login_check == $login_string)
            {
                // Logged In!!!!
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not logged in
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not logged in
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not logged in
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using sec_session_start() that I guess recreates session ID try using normal session_start()

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to include the code for that function. It does use session_start(), just inside of a function that sets other params.

Comment: As I said session_regenerate_id() generates new session ID , and what happens is while you try to load new page , the first one ends and sets new session id, while second page has already sent old session id that expired.  Try commenting out `// session_regenerate_id();`

Comment: Derp that fixed it, thank you so much! Should I close this or do you want to make that the answer so I can accept?

Comment: close it no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add an answer as this can help others.
So using `sec_session_start()` will use different SESSION ID on every page request, particularly

`session_regenerate_id();`

If your site loads a page very slow and user opens a another link on you page while first page is not loaded fully SESSION ID will be lost hence causing a problem.

Just remove `session_regenerate_id();`  from `sec_session_start` function.